# use jq to format output and convert timestamp

Tags: json, jq

I have the following code, which lists all the current aws lambda functions on my account:

```
aws lambda list-functions --region eu-west-1 | jq -r '.Functions | .[] | .FunctionName' | xargs -L1 -I {} aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name /aws/lambda/{} | jq 'select(.logStreams[-1] != null)' | jq -r '.logStreams | .[] | [.arn, .lastEventTimestamp] | @csv'
```

that returns

```
aws:logs:eu-west-1:****:log-group:/aws/lambda/admin-devices-block-master:log-stream:2018/01/23/[$LATEST]64965367852942f490305cb8707d81b4",1516717768514
```

i am only interested in `admin-devices-block-master` and i want to convert the timestamp `1516717768514` in as `strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p")`

so it should just return:

```
"admin-devices-block-master",1516717768514
```

i tried

```
aws lambda list-functions --region eu-west-1 | jq -r '.Functions | .[] | .FunctionName' | xargs -L1 -I {} aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name /aws/lambda/{} | jq 'select(.logStreams[-1] != null)' | jq -r '.logStreams | .[] | [.arn,[.lastEventTimestamp|./1000|strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p")]]' 
jq: error: strflocaltime/1 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.logStreams | .[] | [.arn,[.lastEventTimestamp|./1000|strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p")]]                                                      
jq: 1 compile error
^CException ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

any advice is much appreciated

Comment: can you provide a small json example a a input ?

Comment: `strflocaltime()` requires `jq` version 1.6. What version do you have?

Comment: An alternative is to use `strftime()`.

Comment: @oliv i have `jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe` will update

Comment: Note that static binaries can be downloaded from https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/ That is how I replaced my "jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe" version in Debian Buster.

Answer (score 1):

`strflocaltime` need jq version 1.6 , thanks to @oliv to remark it .

This is a very simple example that will replace a EPOCH with milliseconds  by a local time .

```
date  -d @1572892409
Mon Nov  4 13:33:29 EST 2019

echo '{ "ts" : 1572892409356 , "id": 2 , "v": "foobar" } ' | \
          jq '.ts|=( ./1000|strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p")) '

{
  "ts": "2019-11-04 01:33PM",
  "id": 2,
  "v": "foobar"
}
```

A second version that test if `ts` exists

```
( 
  echo '{ "ts" : 1572892409356 , "id": 2 , "v": "foobar" } ' ; 
  echo '{ "id":3 }' ; 
  echo '{ "id": 4 , "v": "barfoo" }' 
) | jq 'if .ts != null 
        then  ( .ts|=( ./1000|strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p")) ) 
        else  . 
        end '
```

Comment: thanks for this, very helpful, i got one error
`jq: error (at <stdin>:8686): strflocaltime/1 requires parsed datetime inputs`

it is when there is no timestamp

is there a way to ignore this, this is what i have so far?

`aws lambda list-functions --region eu-west-1 | jq -r '.Functions | .[] | .FunctionName' | xargs -L1 -I {} aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name /aws/lambda/{} | jq 'select(.logStreams[-1] != null)' | jq -r '.logStreams | .[] | [.arn,.lastEventTimestamp|=(strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p"))]'
`